# Не удается разобрать формат объекта

Tags: json

Есть .json файл с содержимым:

```
ItemBlueprint
{
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "itemDef": {
                "instanceID": 126858
            },
            "amount": 20.0
        },
        {
            "itemDef": {
                "instanceID": 127252
            },
            "amount": 200.0
        }
    ],
    "userCraftable": true,
    "isResearchable": true,
    "rarity": 1,
    "NeedsSteamItem": false,
    "blueprintStackSize": -1,
    "time": 60.0,
    "amountToCreate": 1,
    "UnlockLevel": 6,
    "UnlockPrice": 3
}
```

Что это за формат такой и как мне его прочитать так же, как XML, например?

Comment: Из Вашего вопроса ясно только то что у Вас проблемы с чтением, тогда возможно решение вашей проблемы это очки или поход к окулисту? Если же я все таки неправильно интерпретировал Ваш вопрос - расширьте его, например где и как вы его хотите прочитать. Ну а по теме это формат часто использующийся при обмене данными.

Comment: про то что это за формат такой https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: Забыл уточнить. Средствами, например, PHP или Javascript необходимо получить доступ к элементам этого содержимого.

Comment: Я вижу, что это json, но меня смущает ItemBlueprint перед объектом.

Answer (score 1):

Всё, кроме строки "ItemBlueprint" - это формат JSON. Прочитать его можно при помощи стандартных функций языка (например, JSON.parse в javascript и json_decode в php).

Что означает строка "ItemBlueprint" - об этом можно лишь догадываться. А лучше всего спросить (или прочитать в документации) у того, кто этот файл сформировал. Интуиция мне подсказывает, что это название класса, объект которого был сериализирован при помощи JSON. Но это исключительно мои догадки.

Как эту строку отделить от JSON - думаю, вы сами разберетесь, дело не хитрое.